# $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ are the root of $x^3-x^2+px-1=0$. $(\alpha^3+1)(\beta^3+1)(\gamma^3+1)=2019$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

$\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ are the root of $x^3-x^2+px-1=0$. $(\alpha^3+1)(\beta^3+1)(\gamma^3+1)=2019$. What is the product of all possible value of $p$?

Note that $p$ could be a complex number.

I tried some basic Vieta's formulas, couldn't find easy way to simplify...

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2463195) might help even more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^3-x^2+px-1=0 \Rightarrow (x^3-1)^3-(x^2-px)^3=0 \Rightarrow x^9+(3p-.4)x^6+(p^3-3p+3)-1=0.$$ 
Let us transform this equation by $y=x^3+1 \rightarrow x=(y-1)^{1/3}$. Then
we get a cubic Eq. for $y$ as
$$y^3+y^2(3p-7)+(p^3-9p+14)y-p^3+6p-9=0,$$ $y_1, y_2, y_3$ are its roots.
Then $$y_1 y_2 y_3=p^3-6p+9=2019 \Rightarrow p^3-6p-2010=0.$$
The roots of $p$ are $p_1,p_2,p_3$ and their product is: $p_1p_2p_3=2010$

Answer (score 0):

$$(x^3-1)^3=(x^2-px)^3$$

$$(x^3)^3-1-3x^3(x^3-1)=(x^3)^2-p^3(x^3)-3px^3(x^3-1)$$

Replace $x^3+1$ with $y$

$$(y-1)^3-3(y-1)(y-2)=(y-1)^2-p^3(y-1)-3p(y-1)(y-2)$$

$$y^3+(\cdots)y^2+(\cdots)y-1-6+1-p^3+6p=0$$

Now apply Vieta's formula

Answer (score 0):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}$
Lazy answer, in line with some of the comments: let
$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=x^3-x^2+px-1\\
g(x)&=x^3+1\text{.}
\end{align}$$
Then the given is
$$\Res(f,g)=2019\text{,}$$
where $\Res$ denotes the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) of $f$ and $g$.

Resultants are implemented in most computer algebra systems. In this case, we [find](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Resultant%5Bx%5E3-x%5E2+%2Bp+x-1%2Cx%5E3%2B1%2Cx%5D)
$$\Res(f,g)=p^3-6p+9$$
so
$$p^3-6p-2010=0\text{.}$$
Since the discriminant of the polynomial on the left is [non-zero](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Discriminant%5Bp%5E3-6p-2010%2Cp%5D), the product of possible values for $p$ is equal to $2010$.

Comment: thanks, why is it that $Res(f,g)=2019$?  I just looked up the definition of resultant, not too clear to me why we can go from the definition to this part.

Comment: If $f(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)$ then $\mathrm{Res}(f,g)=g(\alpha)g(\beta)g(\gamma)$; consider $g(x)=x^3+1$.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your answer, as I learned something new here, but I accepted another one just because that your answer involves using computers. But again, really I appreciate your help.